# How to prevent face detection bounding box from being drawn in mediapipe android

Tags: android, face-detection, mediapipe

I recently (less than a week), started using the mediapipe library to implement face detection, so please apologies in advance. So far I have been able to build an android aar and use this aar in my application, with success. However I do not want the bounding box that appears over the detected face.

- I changed the ***DetectionsToRenderDataCalculatorOptions->thickness*** value in *face_detection_mobile_gpu.pbtxt* from 4.0 to 0.0, rebuilt the graph and applied to my app with no success
- I have tried removing the ***DetectionsToRenderDataCalculatorOptions*** from the *DetectionsToRenderDataCalculator* node in *face_detection_mobile_gpu.pbtxt*, rebuilt the graph and applied to my app with no success.
- I even commented out the following lines from *detections_to_render_data.cc*, rebuilt the aar, applied to my project with no success.

`render_annotation->mutable_color()->set_r(options.color().r());`
`render_annotation->mutable_color()->set_g(options.color().g());`
`render_annotation->mutable_color()->set_b(options.color().b());`
`render_annotation->set_thickness(options.thickness());`

I should mention that in all the cases above, the bounding box is drawn with a very thin black line (like a "default" setting).
Any tips on this will be appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just found a simple hack to this solution, you can comment out the rendering code used to render the render data in the calculator. I have tried with FaceMesh example by comment out following lines in calculators/util/annotation_overlay_calculator.cc

```
 const RenderData& render_data = cc->Inputs().Get(id).Get<RenderData>();
 renderer_->RenderDataOnImage(render_data);
```

and

```
for (const RenderData& render_data : render_data_vec) {
    renderer_->RenderDataOnImage(render_data);
}
```